# Open Word Document From Dynamic Directory VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a program for which I have developed a user guide. I have placed this user guide within the project directory. I created a MenuStrip Item by which to open the user guide in Word on the user's machine. I was successfully able to do this with the following code:

```
Try
        userGuide = MSWord.Documents.Open("C:Users\administrator\Documents\VisualStudio2010\Project3\UserGuide.doc")

        MSWord.WindowState = Word.WdWindowState.wdWindowStateNormal
        MSWord.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error has prevented the document from opening. The document may not be available." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Please try one of the following options:" & vbCrLf & _
               "- Check to see if the document is already open" & vbCrLf & _
               "- Restart the program")
    End Try
```

The problem is, the path used to open the file will not exist on the users machine. This is a standalone system, so no file share can be created in which to place the document, therefore no common path can be coded.

Is there a way to code dynamic paths? Perhaps something like:

```
userGuide = MSWord.Documents.Open("%windir%\UserGuide.doc")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious. Why you have decided to give to your users a word document as UserGuide? What happen if they don't have word installed?

Comment: @Steve if they don't have Word installed they can download OpenOffice, it'll open .doc and .docx. Or they can realize it's 2012, and MS Office is not prohibitively expensive. :D

Comment: Yes of course there are other possibilities, but in this way your users can edit the document. Is this an option acceptable or desired? (Usually I print a PDF from the doc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the document will be stored relative to the install path of the application executable, then start with the [path of the exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx):

```
Dim path As String
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( _
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)

Dim docPath as String;

docPath = Path.Combine(path,"UserGuide.doc");
```